# how to handle empty sets in a list in python

Tags: python, list, set

I have a script that takes columns in files and puts them in a list, finds the min and max values in that list and subtracts them, here is part of the code that does this:

```
for line in f:
    new_n = float(line)
    temp.append(new_n)
min_ = min(temp)
max_ = max(temp)
tot = (max_ - min_)
```

Some files have lists of all 0s, I am getting the error: `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence` how do I handle these empty sets and return 0 if the entire list has 0.

I was guess something like:

```
for num in temp:
    if num == 0:
        tot = 0
    else:
        min_ = min(temp)
        max_ = max(temp)
        tot = (max_ - min_)
```

Answer (score 0):

The file with all zeros is not giving the error... its the file that has no data at all which is troubling.

This error occurs

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

when the argument to the min func is the empty list (or tuple). Your temp list is empty when `min(temp)` gets executed.